# Why are my Avocado Leaves turning bright red?

Tags: leaves

Tree is about 1-2 years old. Some of the leaves are turning bright red, why?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your picture, I wouldn't really call that "bright red". I would say it is brown. Those are patches of dead tissue on the leaves. My avocado tree looks like that when the leaves become damaged; they do turn quite a reddish shade of brown.

Dead portions of the leaves aren't necessarily a danger sign if there is some otherwise explainable reason for the leaf damage. For instance: sunburn, mechanical injury while you are maybe pruning or handling the leaves, heat damage from a nearby "outdoor grilling incident",... or some other known cause.

I'm no avocado expert, but the dead patches are so random looking and the rest of the plant looks so vigorous, that (unless someone else comes up with a more educated analysis) I wouldn't worry right now.

Comment: We have another avocado tree, and i've never see the leaves turn that bright. Not sure.